# SQL Query question - How to select groups of rows using commonalities

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm working census data, and I wish to provide the ability to search for records by providing a list of names. The idea is that if you know the name or 2 or 3 family members, you will be able to exclude all addresses which don't have those names.  Consider this example dataset (Address, Family Name, Forename):

---

"Residents of a house 2 in Janemount Lower (Cork No. 4 Urban (part of), Cork)", "Gamble", "Julia"
"Residents of a house 2 in Janemount Lower (Cork No. 4 Urban (part of), Cork)", "Gamble", "Richard"
"Residents of a house 2 in Janemount Lower (Cork No. 4 Urban (part of), Cork)", "Gamble", "Hannah"
"Residents of a house 2 in Janemount Lower (Cork No. 4 Urban (part of), Cork)", "Gamble", "Helen"

---

A search for Julia, Hannah and Helen should be able to return all 4 rows as they share a common address. It sounds simple enough, but I'm having trouble with this one. Cursors are out because of the size of the dataset. Any ideas?

*(Needless to say, I've simplified this somewhat as I'm ignoring the Family-name part of the search for now)*

Comment: Are you asking search on "Julia" should give you 4 records?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Are you asking search on "Julia" should give you 4 records? - Yes, exactly. Just Julia would return the whole family at the address.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM YourTable A
JOIN (  SELECT Address, COUNT(*) Quant
        FROM YourTable
        WHERE Forename IN ('Julia','Hannah','Helen')
        GROUP BY Address
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Forename) > 2) B
ON A.Address = B.Address
```

Comment: This would also return results if there were 2 Julias and a Hannah at the same address. You would need `COUNT(DISTINCT Forename)` to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [relational divisio](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)n problem.

```
SELECT Address, FamilyName, Forename
FROM   YourTable
WHERE  Address IN (SELECT Address
                   FROM   YourTable
                   WHERE  Forename IN ( 'Julia', 'Hannah', 'Helen' )
                   GROUP  BY Address
                   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Forename) = 3)
```

Or

```
WITH Names(name)
     AS (SELECT 'Julia'
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Hannah'
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Helen')
SELECT Address,
       FamilyName,
       Forename
FROM   YourTable y1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   Names n
                   WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                                     FROM   YourTable y2
                                     WHERE  y1.Address = y2.Address
                                            AND y2.Forename = n.Name))
```

Answer (score 1):

This query:

```
       select streetaddress, count(*) as occupantcount
       from census
       where firstname in ("Julia", "Hannah", "Helen")
       group by streetaddress
       order by occupantcount desc
```

would return the address and number of occupants at each address wherever one of the occupants has one of the first names  in the IN() list, and order the results in most-occupants-to-least-occupants order.  Variations on this same principle (grouping by address) can get you other sorts of information.  You can apply successive filters to the results to zero-in on your desired rows.

Comment: Adding `HAVING COUNT(*) >=3` would be closer to what the OP describes.

Comment: We're teaching him to fish, not handing him a fish. Besides, I added that he could add successive filters, which would include HAVING( ).

Comment: Well, he wants to fish big blue whales. Not fish that are either blue, big or whales :)

Comment: I have to add that you clearly state that your answer is not a complete anmswer and what exactly it results.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.address
     , t.familyname
     , t.forename 
  FROM yourTable t
  WHERE t.address IN 
    -- search subquery
    ( SELECT s1.address 
        FROM yourTable s1
          JOIN yourTable s2
            ON s2.address = s1.address
          JOIN yourTable s3
            ON s3.address = s1.address
        WHERE s1.forename = "Julia"
          AND s2.forename = "Hannah"
          AND s3.forename = "Helen"
    )
  ORDER BY t.address
         , t.familyname
         , t.forename 
;
```

2nd solution:

```
SELECT t.address
     , t.familyname
     , t.forename 
  FROM yourTable t
  WHERE EXISTS 
    -- search subquery
    ( SELECT * 
        FROM yourTable s1
          JOIN yourTable s2
            ON s2.address = s1.address
          JOIN yourTable s3
            ON s3.address = s1.address
        WHERE s1.forename = "Julia"
          AND s2.forename = "Hannah"
          AND s3.forename = "Helen"
          AND s1.address = t.address
    )
  ORDER BY t.address
         , t.familyname
         , t.forename 
;
```

3rd solution:

```
SELECT t.address
     , t.familyname
     , t.forename
  FROM yourTable t
  WHERE  -- search subqueries
    EXISTS
      ( SELECT * 
          FROM yourTable s1
            WHERE s1.forename= "Julia"
              AND s1.address = t.address
      )
    AND EXISTS
      ( SELECT * 
          FROM yourTable s2
            WHERE s2.forename = "Hannah"
              AND s2.address = t.address
      )
    AND EXISTS
      ( SELECT * 
          FROM yourTable s3
            WHERE s3.forename = "Helen"
              AND s3.address = t.address
      )
  ORDER BY t.address
         , t.familyname
         , t.forename 
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you index forename and address this should be straightforward and fast:

```
SELECT a.Address as CommonAddress
FROM (SELECT Address FROM Names WHERE Forename = 'Julia') a
INNER JOIN (SELECT Address FROM Names WHERE Forename = 'Richard') b ON a.Address=b.Address
INNER JOIN (SELECT Address FROM Names WHERE Forename = 'Helen') c on b.Address=c.Address
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use a subquery to find the address that is common to all of the supplied names, and to return all records at that address.

```
declare @people table (
    address varchar(255),
    familyName varchar(255),
    forename varchar(255)
)

insert into @people
values ('Residents of a house 2 in Janemount Lower (Cork No. 4 Urban (part of), Cork)', 'Gamble', 'Julia')
insert into @people
values ('Residents of a house 2 in Janemount Lower (Cork No. 4 Urban (part of), Cork)', 'Gamble', 'Richard')
insert into @people
values ('Residents of a house 2 in Janemount Lower (Cork No. 4 Urban (part of), Cork)', 'Gamble', 'Hannah')
insert into @people
values ('Residents of a house 2 in Janemount Lower (Cork No. 4 Urban (part of), Cork)', 'Gamble', 'Helen')
insert into @people
values ('Residents of a house 2 somewhere else (Cork No. 4 Urban (part of), Cork)', 'Cooper', 'Helen')

select people.*
from @people as people
where people.address in (
    select address
    from @people
    where forename in ('Julia', 'Hannah', 'Helen')
    group by address
    having count(forename) >= 3 -- This must be equal to the number of names searched for
)
```

One issue with this solution is that, if there are three Hannahs living at the same address, the query will return those people, even if Julia and Helen are not living there.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @namecount int;
DECLARE @forenames TABLE (name varchar(50));
INSERT INTO @forenames
VALUES ('...'),
       ('...'),
       ('...');
SELECT @namecount = COUNT(*) FROM @forenames;

/* list all people by addresses that are shared by people
   whose forenames are included in @forenames */
SELECT cd.*
FROM CensusData cd
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT d.Address
    FROM CensusData d
      INNER JOIN @forenames f ON d.Forename = f.Name
    GROUP BY d.Address
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT d.Forename) >= @namecount
  ) filter ON cd.Address = filter.Address

/* same for family names */
SELECT cd.*
FROM CensusData cd
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT d.[Family Name]
    FROM CensusData d
      INNER JOIN @forenames f ON d.Forename = f.Name
    GROUP BY d.Address
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT d.Forename) >= @namecount
  ) filter ON cd.[Family Name]= filter.[Family Name]

/* and so on fro other criteria */
```

You can also combine criteria, if needed.

Answer (score -1):

```
select *
from dataset
where address = (
    select address
    from dataset
    where famly_name = 'Hannah' and forename = 'Gamble'
)
```

Comment: Downvoters need to put a reason or it does no good for posterity seeking a good answer. All they will know is this got downvoted!

Comment: (i did not downvote but:) This will only find those who have same address with anyone named Hannah Gamble (plus you have interchanged forename and familyname)

Comment: @yper Each of the 8 answers came from a different interpretation of the requirement. This is one of them.

Comment: "*The idea is that if you know the name or 2 or 3 family members, you will be able to exclude all addresses which don't have those names*". Sorry, but I don't see 2 or 3 names in your answer.

Answer (score -1):

You could start with something like this assuming address is to be matched exactly. It needs to be tweaked as you would most likely see some dups

```
Select
    T1.*
From
    TableName T1
Inner Join
    TableName T2
On
    T1.Address = T2.Address
Where
    T1.ForeName = 'Julia'
```

Comment: Downvoters need to put a reason or it does no good for posterity seeking a good answer. All they will know is this got downvoted!